# GNOME 3 Ctrl+Alt+D (show desktop)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, desktop

I recently upgraded my system to GNOME 3. In previous versions of GNOME, the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> would hide all open windows and show the Desktop. This shortcut was eliminated from GNOME 3 along with the concept of a Desktop. The Desktop metaphor does, however, exist in GNOME 3 "fallback mode" (which I am using).

I would like to reinstate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I know at least two ways of creating key combinations in GNOME. One is through System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts, and the other is through `gconf-editor` > apps > metacity. From either of these environments, I can pair a command with the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The problem is that I don't know what command will trigger a "Show Desktop" event. Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Hide all normal windows

Click the second field which says `Disabled` and type in a key combination of choice (e.g., `Ctrl+Alt+D`).

System restart may be required for changes to take effect.

Comment: System restart is not needed.

Comment: At worst, if the changes don't take effect, simply restart gnome shell.

Comment: no restart is needed

Answer (score 0):

In mint13 the shortcut as default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.